# When a class is created in Python, and an object referencing it is used, how would you use the name of the object in the class?

Tags: python, class, object

I apologize if the question doesn't make sense. I don't really know the correct terminology. But, for example, if I had this

```
class Monster:
    def death(self):
        print(monster_name, " is dead.")

john = Monster()
bill = Monster()
dave = Monster()

john.death()
bill.death()
dave.death()
```

How would I get monster_name in the Monster class to be equal to john, bill, or dave?

Comment: Why not just pass the name as an argument to the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't refer to name of a variable (It's possible but that's dark magic :D)

You have to pass the name to class as a parameter:

```
class Monster:
    def __init__ (self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def greet (self):
        print ("Hello, I'm", self.name, "of age", self.age, ".")

person = Monster("Monster",340)
person.greet() #prints Hello, I'm Monster of age 340 .
```

And you can change it later:

```
person.name = "John"
person.greet() #prints Hello, I'm John of age 340 .

person.name = "Mary"
person.age = 60
person.greet() #prints Hello, I'm Mary of age 60 .
```

Or if you want you can change it with method:

```
class Monster:
   def __init__ (self, name, age):
       self.name = name
       self.age = age

   def greet (self):
       print("Hello, I'm", self.name, "of age", self.age, ".")

   def rename (self, new_name):
       self.name = new_name

   def new_age (self, new_age):
       self.age = new_age

person = Monster("Bob", 35)
person.greet() # prints Hello, I'm Bob of age 35 .

person.rename("John")
person.new_age(36)
person.greet() # prints Hello, I'm John of age 36 .
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class Monster:

    def __init__(self, monster_name):
        self.monster_name = monster_name

    def death(self):
        print(self.monster_name, "is dead.")

john = Monster("john")
bill = Monster("bill")
dave = Monster("dave")

john.death()
bill.death()
dave.death()
```

one way of doing this

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the name as a parameter.

```
class Monster:
    def death(self, monster_name):
        print(monster_name, " is dead.")

monster = Monster()

monster.death('john')
monster.death('bill')
monster.death('dave')
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a variable inside class and store the name specifically while instantiating the object. Like -

```
john = Monster('john')
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need variable names the same as the monsters:

```
>>> monsters = [Monster('john'),
...             Monster('bill'),
...             Monster('dave')]

>>> for monster in monsters:
...     monster.death()
john is dead.
bill is dead.
dave is dead.
```

where `Monster` has its own `name` member variable:

```
class Monster(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def death(self):
        print(self.name, "is dead.")
```

edit:

Variables are labels for objects. An object can have many labels:

```
>>> john = Monster('george')
>>> paul = john
```

`paul` and `john` are both labels for the monster with name `george`.

```
>>> john.death()
george is dead.

>>> paul.death()
george is dead.
```

When the object carries its own name, the distinction of the variable name between objects of the same type becomes unimportant or even misleading. They are all `monster`.